# How to split string array?

Tags: java, android, string, text

It worked but it took the last song settext for all

```
for (int i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {
      String SongsName = items[i];
      String [] abcd = SongsName.split("_");

      if(abcd[0] != null)
      {
          txtTitle.setText(abcd[0]);
          txt2.setText(abcd[1]);
      }
      else
      {
          txtTitle.setText("Zero"); 
      }
}
```

How does it show each line? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add an example of the current input and output

Comment: Example is one of my items

Comment: Example is one of my items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After splitting the string, you end up with an array of song names. That array has an undefined number of items inside so you cannot just reference abcd[0] and abcd[1] and expect to see all songs. You need another loop that will iterate through all your song names in variable abcd.

Maybe I did not understand properly though, if variable abcd contains just one song name and you are just splitting to get the different pices of information for that song, then here is what is happening: you are looping through all the songs but you are overwriting txtTitle and txt2 everytime, so in the end, you end up with only the last one showing.

Comment: Yes, txtTitle has been overwritten, but txtTitle is a line in the listview and how can I position it correctly?